# Queens on a 4x4 chessboard.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to place four queens on a 4 by 4 chessboard so that no two queens attack one another?

I have tried to look for an algorithm but I didn't find anything specific.Also what would be the difference between superQueens and regular Queens?

Comment: It maybe helpful to look at wikipedia first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Counting_solutions
There is a good algorithm described here as well.
http://andrewjonesblog.azurewebsites.net/solving-nqueens-using-bitwise-operators/

Comment: Thank you. I checked that out. The more I look at this though it seems that there are 0 ways. Each queen has to go on a row on a separate column. Thus the only way to do that is by having a diagonal line.

Comment: For regular queens the answer is 2. Brute force works fine for such a small board. First, note that a queen can't be on a corner square. What is a superQueen?

Comment: 2 queens can't be on a same diagonal

Comment: I know. So that gives me 0 ways, no?

Comment: No, not a diagonal line, queens can move diagonally. One way is queens on a2, b4, c1, d3.

Comment: If you start by putting a queen on a side square (not a corner) then it's clear where the other 3 queens have to go.

Comment: Ok. I believe that there are 2 ways, then.

Comment: You haven't said what a "superqueen" is. If you mean a piece which can move like a queen or knight (traditionally called an *amazon*), then the answer is 0 ways.

Comment: I don't know what is it is. From the research I did, that term came up so I was curious. I don't believe that this is the case.